# Typecasting based on a variable

Tags: c#, comparison, casting

How would I go about the following...  I have a control that can be bound to different data types... String, Int, Int32, DateTime, etc... but generically the result is stored into a generic "object" data type.  So, I use another field to identify the EXPECTED type such as..

```
String BoundDataType = "System.String"   // or System.Int32 or date/time, etc.
object ChosenValue;
```

For comparison purposes, I would now have to enforce typecasting of expected format, such as

```
(DataBoundType)ChosenValue == (DataBoundType)TestAgainstThisValue;
```

I know i could put inside a switch, or overloaded functions with different Signatures per data type, but looking for a more generic way to handle directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need a separate `BoundDataType` property - `object.GetType()` will suffice.

As for comparison, most standard types implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface, which can be used to test for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`-Class

Answer (score 0):

Try

TestAgainstThisValue.GetType()

to get the type of the variable

Answer (score 0):

you can use object.GetType() to get the type of the variable.

Then you can use Convert.ChangeType(object,type) to make the conversion.

```
object conv = Convert.ChangeType(ChosenValue,ChosenValue.GetType());
```

this should work.